# The terminology for a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ which is continuous and open but not necessarily bijective

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

What is the terminology for a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ which is continuous and open but not necessarily bijective (For example $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$)
I can't find it in the literature.

Thanks

Comment: You already mentioned the terminology, namely "open". What else do you expect? Many authors require open maps to be continuous in addition. So, no need for an extra terminology.  And, if not, it's probably more intuitive to say "open and continuous" rather than introducing a further notation.

Comment: BTW, $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb  {R}, f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ is not open, since $f(\mathbb {R} ^2)  = [0, \infty)$ is not open in $\mathbb R$. You have to restrict the codomain.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:X\to Y$ that is continuous and open but not necessarily bijective is called an open map. An open map is a function that preserves the topological property of openness.

Open maps are used in topology and are an important concept in the study of continuous functions. They are a generalization of open functions, which are functions that are both continuous and open and are always surjective (i.e., they map onto their range).

Open maps are also known as onto maps or surjective maps. They are defined as follows:

A function $f:X\to Y$ is an open map if it is continuous and for every open set $U\subset Y$, the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.
A function $f:X\to Y$ is an onto map or a surjective map if it maps every element in the range $f(X)$ to at least one element in the codomain $Y$.
For example, the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is an open map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It is not a bijective map because it is not one-to-one, but it is surjective because it maps onto its range $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is not surjective with codomain $\mathbb{R}$ because it doesn’t map onto negative values

Comment: You are correct that the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is not surjective with codomain $\mathbb{R}$ because it does not map onto negative values. However, this does not mean that the function is not an open map.

To clarify, a function $f:X\to Y$ is an open map if it is continuous and for every open set $U\subset Y$, the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. An open map does not need to be surjective.

Comment: In the case of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, it is an open map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ because it is continuous and for every open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$, the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, it is not surjective because it does not map every element in its codomain $\mathbb{R}$ to at least one element in its range $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was only correcting the last statement of the answer, namely “it is surjective because it maps onto its range $\mathbb{R}$”

Comment: ah okay, thanks for the remark :)

Comment: @MarcoDJ01: 1. you mismatched continuous and open. A map is continuous, if preimages of open sets are open. It is open, if images of open sets are open. 2. you can not *define* "a map is open", by saying "if it is open". 3 Some authors require open maps to be continuous in addition. 4. But I have never seen that open maps are surjective by definition.